# ErrorDocument 410 gives me back a 302 header

Tags: redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I've deleted several pages and tags from my site, and bases on my SEO recommendations I've redirected them to 410.

I've done that in my .htaccess file this way:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/lorem/?$ - [G]
RewriteRule ^tag/ipsum/?$ - [G]
RewriteRule ^tag/dolor/?$ - [G]
RewriteRule ^tag/amet/?$ - [G]
```

At the end of the .htaccess I've defined the ErrorDocument 410 and I want it to go to a page I've created on Wordpress

```
ErrorDocument 410 http://myhost.localhost/error-410/
```

The thing is it sends me to that page, but it gives me a 302 instead a 410 on the headers

```
Request URL: http://myhost.localhost/tag/routers/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do this in Apache/`.htaccess` when using WordPress unfortunately. When you specify an absolute URL as the ErrorDocument it will indeed trigger a 302 redirect, however, if you use a root-relative URL-path (as you would normally/should do) then it won't work with WordPress since WP looks at the `REQUEST_URI` variable in order to route the URL. You need to do this entirely inside WordPress. Perhaps include code in your `404.php` file to check for these URLs and override the response?

Comment: What you mean inside wordpress @MrWhite ?

Comment: As in the PHP code that drives the WordPress CMS. _Aside:_ If you wanted to serve a non-WordPress 410 error document then you could do this using `ErrorDocument` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: What I don't understand is how can I manage this inside WP.